# How do I switch to git-svn compatibility mode in SmartGit on Windows

Tags: git-svn, smartgit

The documentation on the SmartGit website and in their shipped documentation pdf file talks about having a [Normal mode and a git-svn compatibility mode](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/documentation?page=concepts-svn).

My question is: How do I switch to git-svn compatibility mode in SmartGit on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository will be in *compatibility* mode exactly when it has been cloned with `git-svn` instead of SmartGit.